# GeoServer SLD rounding values after division

Tags: geoserver, sld

I am doing  normalisation of two fields on GeoServer.

```
     <ogc:Div>
       <ogc:PropertyName>PERSONS</ogc:PropertyName>
       <ogc:PropertyName>LAND_KM</ogc:PropertyName>
     </ogc:Div>
```

Now I want to round the result of Division to *n* decimal places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To simply format it you can use the `numberFormat` [function](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#parsing-and-formatting-functions). This allows you to specify how many digits you want after the decimal point.

Here is an example from [MASS-GIS](https://wiki.state.ma.us/display/massgis/GeoServer+-+SLD+-+numberFormat+Function):

```
    <TextSymbolizer>
        <Label>
          <Function name="numberFormat">
            <Literal>#</Literal>
            <PropertyName xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">CONTOUR_FT</PropertyName>
          </Function>
        </Label>
```

If you also want to round the result there is a `round` function which while return the nearest integer value.